# Use two different physical keyboards with different layouts

Tags: keyboard

My partner and I share a Mac, but we're used to different keyboard layouts.  One of us uses the ABC layout and the other uses the Norwegian layout.  Which is why we have two Bluetooth keyboards connected to the same Mac!

I know that I can press <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to switch layout, but can I set up my Mac so that both keyboards are set up with their respective layout?

So when I press <kbd>Ø</kbd> on the Norwegian keyboard, it should type `ø` and not `;`, and vice versa when I press <kbd>;</kbd> on the ABC keyboard, it should type `;` and not `ø`.

Comment: I think Karabiner can switch layouts according to which keyboard is active, but I don't know the details

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329520/how-to-enable-rules-only-for-specific-keyboard-layout-karabiner

Comment: @TomGewecke I'm not looking for overriding specific keys; I really want the standard ABC and the standard Norwegian layouts to be used by their respective keyboards. I think Karabiner (referred in the answer you linked to) is used to override specific keys?

Comment: What you want is equivalent to karabiner automatically overriding certain keys in the abc layout whenever the Norwegian keyboard is being used.

Comment: @TomGewecke You mean I should te-create the standard Mac Norwegian layout as a list of overrides? That’s a lot of work, almost all non-alphabetical and non-numerical characters (including those behind ⌥) are somewhere else than with ABC. I just want the Mac to switch keyboard layout to the keyboard being used.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do it.  The machine has no way of knowing what is printed on the keys  of a keyboard, it can only map the standard keycodes it receives to output characters via .keylayout files or something like Karabiner overrides.  For an alternative layout switcher, see https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa